# View in Browser redirecting to an Error Page

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder, email-studio

I understand that if a Data Extension is either updated or overwritten, the View in Browser Link breaks and the only way around this is to use Sendlog.
Is there a way of not using a Sendlog and use a Data Extension instead to mitigate this issue?

The approach that I am trying to do, is to capture all Personalization related data using InsertDE and resurface the same data within the condition "`if _MessageContext == "VAWP" then`".

I have hit a roadblock with this and I seek help on it.

```
SET @Id = [_subscriberkey]
SET @JobID = [jobid]
SET @ListID = [listid]
SET @BatchID = [_JobSubscriberBatchID]
SET @FIRST_NAME = [FIRST_NAME]
SET @LOYALTY_ID = [LOYALTY_ID]
SET @POINTS = [POINTS]
SET @EMAIL_ADDRESS = [EMAIL_ADDRESS]
SET @EmailName = [emailname_]

if @JobID > 0 then 
    InsertDE("DE Name","Id",@Id,"JobID",@JobID,"ListID",@ListID,"BatchID",@BatchID,"FIRST_NAME",@FIRST_NAME,"LOYALTY_ID",@LOYALTY_ID,"POINTS",@POINTS,"EMAIL_ADDRESS",@EMAIL_ADDRESS,"EmailName",@EmailName)
endif
]%%
%%[
if _MessageContext == "VAWP" then
    SET @decount = DataExtensionRowCount("DE Name")
    SET @rows = LookupOrderedRows("DE Name",@decount, "JobID DESC","JobID",@JobID,"ListID",@ListID,"BatchID",@BatchID,"Id",@Id,"EmailName",@EmailName)
    SET @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)
    IF @rowCount > 0 THEN
        SET @subrow = Row(@rows,1)
        SET @loyaltyID = field(@subrow,"LOYALTY_ID") 
        SET @points = field(@subrow,"POINTS")
        SET @campaignID = field(@subrow,"EmailName")
        SET @email = field(@subrow,"EMAIL_ADDRESS")
        SET @sha256Email = SHA256(@email,'UTF-16')  
    ENDIF
ENDIF
]%%
```

Comment: Please provide us with the complete ampscript you have built, both the part writing the data to the data extension, as well as what is fetching these records in the VAWP context.

Comment: @LukasLunow I have added the code that I am using for this test.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way of preserving the VAWP is by only *updating* your sending audience in a Data Extension (e.g. never overwriting it) -- then simply sending to a *filtered* audience of "new" rows in the data extension.

Caveats: IIRC, you can only send to a single filtered DE audience. Executing a filter isn't very performant if you have a large regular sending audience.

Also, generally speaking, I'd evaluate the number of clicks you get on the VAWP before undertaking some elaborate system for preserving it.  I suspect there won't be enough engagement to justify building something to handle it.

Comment: Hi, that's interesting. Could you elaborate on the performance part (I'll gladly open a new question if this gets too lengthy) - what you're saying is that using a Filtered DE (created using data filters) will have a different sending performance than an SQL based one - Is that correct? Or did you mean something else by "filtered DE audience"? thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, Data Filter would not be an option for us, as we receive our data from a CDP Platform, on which we run some additional Queries to get our final Audience Count to be used in Journey.

Comment: Yes, @JonasLamberty, in my experience, filters don't perform as well as queries with larger data sets.  That sentence of mine is poorly worded.  I don't think the sends are slower, just the selection.

Comment: @LijoJohns I'd still take a look at click engagement with your VAWP links.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Thanks @AdamSpriggs